# how to redirect everything from https to http except WP admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After a migration we have the below in the WP htaccess to redirect everything from https to http:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://examplesite.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But we want to have the wordpress admin on SSL.

What exception should be added to the above rule and how?

Would this be the right way to do it?

**Update:**
How can I exclude /wp-admin/ and wp-login.php from the above condition? (please, note the blog is in the subfolder /blog and the htaccess is there too)

Comment: I don't know but just a comment - ^(.*)$ looks like a regular expression to me, so does wordpress admin generate a specific URL you could exclude from the rule with a more precise regular expression?

Comment: That is also part of my question. I guess /wp-admin/ and the wp-login.php are the things that should not be caught.

Answer (score 2):

The wordpress codex is actually providing a good solution to handle your request: https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Take a quick look and you'll find every change needed.

Comment: The problem is the special circumstances caused by the mentioned rewrite rule that we have.